# What is an efficent way to refactor this code?

Tags: javascript, refactoring, processing, p5.js

***The Rundown***

The game is Tic-Tac-Toe.

I have a huge, load time eating function that I know can be trimmed down, but I don't even know where to start...

**`mousePressed()` function**

```
function mousePressed() {
    // First Row
    if (mouseX >= 0 && mouseX <= scl && mouseY >= 0 && mouseY <= scl) {
        if (turn) {
            drawX(0, 0);
        } else {
            drawY(0, 0);
        }
    } else if (mouseX >= scl && mouseX <= scl * 2 && mouseY >= 0 && mouseY <= scl) {
        if (turn) {
            drawX(1, 0);
        } else {
            drawY(1, 0);
        }
    } else if (mouseX >= scl * 2 && mouseX <= width && mouseY >= 0 && mouseY <= scl) {
        if (turn) {
            drawX(2, 0);
        } else {
            drawY(2, 0);
        }
    }
    // Second Row
    else if (mouseX >= 0 && mouseX <= scl && mouseY >= scl && mouseY <= scl * 2) {
        if (turn) {
            drawX(0, 1);
        } else {
            drawY(0, 1);
        }
    } else if (mouseX >= scl && mouseX <= scl * 2 && mouseY >= scl && mouseY <= scl * 2) {
        if (turn) {
            drawX(1, 1);
        } else {
            drawY(1, 1);
        }
    } else if (mouseX >= scl * 2 && mouseX <= width && mouseY >= scl && mouseY <= scl * 2) {
        if (turn) {
            drawX(2, 1);
        } else {
            drawY(2, 1);
        }
    }
    // Third Row
    else if (mouseX >= 0 && mouseX <= scl && mouseY >= scl * 2 && mouseY <= width) {
        if (turn) {
            drawX(0, 2);
        } else {
            drawY(0, 2);
        }
    } else if (mouseX >= scl && mouseX <= scl * 2 && mouseY >= scl * 2 && mouseY <= width) {
        if (turn) {
            drawX(1, 2);
        } else {
            drawY(1, 2);
        }
    } else if (mouseX >= scl * 2 && mouseX <= width && mouseY >= scl * 2 && mouseY <= width) {
        if (turn) {
            drawX(2, 2);
        } else {
            drawY(2, 2);
        }
    }
}
```

I know its gonna have something to do with for loops, but I don't know where to start using them.

Comment: what is  'scl'? and can you paste the drawX and drawY function?

Comment: If you have a working code and is looking for a review, you might want to check https://codereview.stackexchange.com. Just make sure you check and follow their guidelines.

Comment: The posted code isn't huge, it likely has almost no effect on load time. You could group all the `mouseX >= 0` in one if branch, `mouseX >= scl` in another branch, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the code in nested loops. For two variables `ix` and `iy` in the range of [0, 2], the condition if the mouse is in the cell indexed by (`ix`, `iy`) is

```js
mouseX >= scl*ix && mouseX < scl*(ix+1) && mouseY >= scl*iy && mouseY < scl*(iy+1)
```

e.g.:

```js
function mousePressed() {

    for (let ix = 0; ix <= 2; ++ix) {
        for (let iy = 0; iy <= 2; ++iy) {

            if ( mouseX >= scl*ix && mouseX < scl*(ix+1) &&
                 mouseY >= scl*iy && mouseY < scl*(iy+1)) {

                if (turn) {
                    drawX(ix, iy);
                } else {
                    drawY(ix, iy);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```